# Consideration for using object vs. array

Tags: json

I have a private JSON object I parse using Python. I now need to make this object public for other developers to use, which is causing me to rethink the structure. The object looks like:

```
{
   "service" : "service-1" : {
      "locale" : "Europe": {
         "city" : "Amsterdam": [
            "name":"AMS-1",
            (other key/value data)
         ],
         "city" : "Brussels": [
            "name":"BRU-1",
            **(other key/value data)**
         ],
         "city" : "France": [
            "name":"FRA-1",
            **(other key/value data)**
         ]         
      },
      "locale" : "USA": {
         "city" : "New York": [
            "name":"NYC-1",
            (other key/value data)
         ],
      }
      **(more locale data)**
   }
}
```

I am not certain if this object will be more difficult to use in other languages, or simply, if the overall structure could be simplified.

Comment: JSON is synonymous across all coding languages; simply changing the key offset isn't going to make things significantly easier or more difficult.

Comment: If a language doesn't support an easy Map data-structure or otherwise good access to "simple" sequence operations, that's on them :} Depending on how one views the keys, that could also written as, eg. `"USA" { "cities": { "New York": { data_about_new_york }, more_cities}, more_usa_data }` .. ie. what is the best way for JSON  structure to *represent the information*? Implementation-in-X *generally* should not be a primary reason to change the JSON format. (Also, FWIW: *City Names are not Unique*.)

Comment: I read years back that you should always have key/value pairs.  What are the caveats / tradeoffs?

Comment: @EthanB "Key/value pairs" meaning..which approach in this case?

Comment: @EthanB Also, the above code in the question is *not* valid JSON..

Comment: @user2864740 what is invalid?

Comment: That "JSON" is invalid. Try http://jsonlint.com